# Android: How to add multiple edit text value to array

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

I have three Edit Text on my activity and i will like to add each value to array if  the Edit Text not empty.

Here is what i want:
EditText 1, EditText 2, EditText 3

```
public static ArrayList<String> arrayValue = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> arrayTitleValue = new ArrayList<String>();
```

if edittext 1 not empty then

```
arrayTitleValue.add("Text Box Value 1")
arrayValue.add(EditText 1.getText.tostring)

if edittext 2 not empty then
Add edittext 2 to variable string e.g arrayValue.add(EditText 2.getText.tostring)
arrayTitleValue.add("Text Box Value 2")

if edittext 3 not empty then
Add edittext 3 to variable string e.g arrayValue.add(EditText 3.getText.tostring)
```

then finally: print the result this way:

```
System.out.println("Title Result: "+arrayTitleValue+" Array Value: "+arrayValue);
```

so at the end of the day i want my result to look like this:

```
Result value for arrayValue= Result1(edit text 1 value),Result2(edit text 2 value),Result3(edit text 3 value)

Result value for arrayTitleValue= ResultTile1("Title 1"),ResultTitle2("Title 2"),ResultTitle3("Title3")
```

i just want very fast way to achieve this task any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You first have to give an id to each of your EditText in your layout file (.xml)

```
android:id="@+id/edittext_1"
```

After in your activity file (.java) you get an EditText object corresponding to each EditText :

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_1);
```

Then you check for your EditText to be filled and if it is, add its value to the List :

```
if(!editText1.getText().toString().equals("")){
    arrayValue.add(editText1.getText().toString();
    arrayTitleValue.add("Text Box Value 1");
}
```